# take the substring out of string in salesforce

Tags: html, salesforce

I am creating the HTML template in Salesforce and below is the value I am fetching from one field that is building address. However, I just need the building number from the entire address. Below is the scenario.
**“Václavské náměstí 785/28, P1 - Alfa Building”**, this is the text and I want to extract the only the number **i.e 785/28.** But the thing is the numbers before and after the `‘/’` varies it can be more than 3 or 2 digits. Trim Left and Right work but can't seem to specify the values dynamically.

Thanks

Comment: You can find the index of first and last numeric digit, then take your substring.

Comment: Hey Rob, Thank you for the comment. IS it possible to give me the code?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code for your above concern. It is in javascript only.

```
        <script>
        function myFunction() {
          var str = "sdfdfv123456/789xvxcv";  // pass your string over here
        var revstr = reverseString(str);
         var firstDigit = str.match(/\d/) 
        var lastDigit = revstr.match(/\d/)
        var findex = str.indexOf(firstDigit);
        var lindex =  str.length - revstr.indexOf(lastDigit);
        function reverseString(str) {
          if (str === "") 
            return "";  
          else
            return reverseString(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);
        }
        var sub_string = str.substring (findex, lindex);
          alert(sub_string) ;
        }
        </script>
```

If any confusion please let me know.